# In Flutter, how to distribute Entity and Model in network call?

Tags: flutter, model, dto

I am currently implementing network communication using the dio library on the flutter. The database is using mongoDB.

At this time, I want to generate entities and dtos necessary for communication, and I have a question about how to implement this part.

The question is, should createDto and updateDto, which are used in requests, inherit entity?

As far as I know, createDto is not null except for table_id and some timestamp values, and updateDto is nullable for almost all values except id.

Therefore, the nullable option values of these two dto fields are different, so it is ambiguous to inherit same entity.

So I don't think createDto and updateDto, which correspond to the request, should inherit Entity. However, it seems that the purpose of distinguishing between entity and dto will be eliminated.

In addition, if not inherited, the dependency between entity and dto is lost.

Which is the answer, not inherited or received?